# How to decode an array in a function which was encoded in another function in php?

Tags: php, function

I have encode $result in one function and try to decode and match with a condition in another function. Here is the code:

```
function postOperation(){
    include("function/db.php");
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $mfsname = $_POST['mfsname'];
        $mfsnumber = $_POST['mfsnumber'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $pin_no = $_POST['pinno'];

        $insert_info = "insert into table_name(name, mfs_name, mfs_number, amount, pin_no) 
        values('$name', '$mfsname', '$mfsnumber', '$amount', '$pin_no')";

        $success=0;
        $insert_final = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_info);
        if($insert_final){
           $success=1;
           $result["success"]=$success;
        }
        json_encode($result);
}

function getOperation(){
        $array = json_decode($result, true);
        if($array["success"] == 1){
           echo "<script>alert('Transaction successful!')</script>";
        }

}
```

Comment: You need to return `$result` from `postOperation` and pass it to `getOperation` (or declare it a global in both functions...)

Comment: What is the result you're experiencing? What is the expected result? Please add some clarification so others can better help you.

Comment: The statement `json_encode($result);` does not have any effect. It encodes the value of `$result` as JSON and drops the encoded value. You should either store it in a variable or, if you want to access it outside the function let the function return it.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical error

`$success=0;
 $result["success"]=$success;  //I have added this line`

and added a `return json_encode($result);`

**See the full code:**

```
function postOperation(){
        include("function/db.php");

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $mfsname = $_POST['mfsname'];
        $mfsnumber = $_POST['mfsnumber'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $pin_no = $_POST['pinno'];

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare("insert into table_name(name, mfs_name, mfs_number, amount, pin_no) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiii", $name, $mfsname, $mfsnumber, $amount, $pin_no);

        $success=0;
        $result["success"]=$success; 
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
           $success=1;
           $result["success"]=$success;
        }

        return json_encode($result);
}

function getOperation($result){
        $array = json_decode($result, true);
        if($array["success"] == 1){
           echo "<script>alert('Transaction successful!')</script>";
        }

}
```

Please test the above function after hardcoding some values for $_POST variables. Then call those functions like below:-

```
$result = postOperation(); 
getOperation($result);
```

And another important thing: Your sql statement is not safe. There will be SQL injection 
Please refer the link : [How to avoid SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You forgot to add a parameter to the `getOperation()` function definition.

Comment: @EI_Vanja,  I have mentioned to hard code some values for `$_POST`  in function `getOperation()`, so there is no need to pass parameters to the function `getOperation()`

Comment: In your proposed answer you are passing a parameter to it (`getOperation($result)`) and inside the function you're doing something with that variable (`$array = json_decode($result, true)`), but you didn't define the function taking a parameter (`function getOperation(){`). This will result in an undefined variable error.